# How to to run program when USB is inserted?

Tags: system

Hi I have one program that I need to run on my server but the problem is that my server don't have any monitor, keyabord and mouse attach to it so I can confirn when windows 7 ask me to run program so is posible to just plug USB Mass Storage device in a computer and computer would execute this without any qestions?

Comment: how about sshing into the server?

Comment: Do you need to do this just once, or regularly?

Comment: Check out the www.usbrubberducky.com for an amusing way to accomplish this. It looks like a thumb drive, but it actually quacks *and types* like a keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could look into using [autorun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoRun) or some variant thereof (e.g. a program that would monitor the USB bus for devices, and automatically run some program when it detects that an appropriate storage device has been connect).

**Bear in mind that, depending on the physical setup, this could be used as an attack vector.**

Comment: Wouldn't setting up autorun be just as difficult as running something from his usb?

Comment: @TheOneWhoPrograms: I imagine that connecting a keyboard, a mouse and a monitor just once, for the purposes of setting this up, should not be a problem. I could, of course, be misunderstanding the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Celeriko said, you should try to find a way into connecting to your server remotely. Whether that be through SSH or a tool such as PUTTY (basically SSH right? I'm not sure off top of my head).

Having a usb automatically execute something would be a security risk and I believe it is restricted for that reason.
Best of luck trying to connect remotely into your server, it shouldn't be too difficult.